# How to open two workspace in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How to open two workspace in eclipse.
When I am truing to open another workspace, it is closing the previous workspace and opening new one.
Same action is being performed when I am switching the workspace,

Comment: Start Eclipse while another instance is running (a dialog will tell you that the current workspace is in use and you can choose another one) or use `-data <path-to-workspace>`.

Comment: Just start a second Eclipse. What operating system are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to multiple work spaces in eclipse windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55161921/how-to-multiple-work-spaces-in-eclipse-windows)

Comment: Really the @howlger comment is the correct answer, proceed to put it how the solution.

Comment: Actually, on **macOs**, starting another Eclipse instance basically put to front the current one, so it doesn't present the ability to choose workspace... You're only left with the cli with `-data`.

Answer (score 1):

The comment and answer shared by @howlger is correct. The `-data` parameter is the key and solution to accomplish the goal

For simplicity - considering we have a script file (.sh)

Therefore for Mac is:

`$STS_HOME/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/MacOS/SpringToolSuite4 -data ${WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY}`

Windows is:

- `$STS_HOME%/SpringToolSuite4 -data ${WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY}`

Be sure to prior execute in the terminal the `bash` command to load the *git* bash - btw git must be defined in the `PATH`

Therefore with just **one** STS installation you are able to open multiple instances where each one is working with a custom and specific (different) *workspace* specified through the `-data` parameter