# How to multiple work spaces in eclipse windows

Tags: eclipse

I tried window with **Window -> New Window**

It is opening new window but when I am doing a action switch work space, it is closing the both window and open new switched work space

Comment: you want to open same workspace in multiple or multiple workspaces?

Comment: @Shakti Pravesh Is this windows you are running on your eclipse instance ?

Answer (score 1):

A single instance of Eclipse can only have one workspace open.

You have to start a separate second Eclipse to open another workspace.

Comment: No you can have single instance of  eclipse and can have multiple workspace from it. I believe and I just tried now.

Comment: @Ros5292 Then tell us what you did. The Eclipse core code only has APIs for a single workspace it cannot possibly support multiple workspaces. You can switch between workspaces but you can't have more that one open at a time in a single instance of Eclipse.

Comment: In windows machine I have single instance of eclipse and from that instance I have 3 workspace running altogether but in Mac Singe instance of eclipse can have only single workspace or can switch to another workspace as you said.

Comment: How did you get the three workspaces? What exactly did you do? Are you sure you are not running multiple instances of Eclipse? On macOs (which I run) it is also possible to start multiple instances of Eclipse to get multiple workspace.

Comment: on windows click on eclipse.exe and it will pop up for selecting workspaces. Browse and select one workspace. It will open up 1st workspace. Click on same eclipse.exe again it will show up pop-up again this time browse and select different workspace. This behaviour only works in windows instance and not in mac.

Comment: @Ros5292 That is creating a new instance of Eclipse each time you run it. On macOS use `open -n /Applications/Eclipse.app` to do the same thing.

Comment: Apologies !! I was thinking it is same instance rather than different. yes you are right.